# Page does not load properly in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

My home page works fine in all browsers but IE9 where part of the page does not load. Below a main image on my page I have 6 boxes with some animation etc. IE 9 does not display those boxes and I don't understand why. Any ideas?

***NOTE*** - I cannot test this in IE 9 (I am using Windows XP) I have had this reported to me and verified this through several people)

Here is the code:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function(){
Engine.Initialize();
if( !$j('body').hasClass('index') && !$j('body').hasClass('homepage') ) {
}
});

var Engine = {

Initialize: function() {
    Engine.Homepage_Animation();
},

Homepage_Animation: function() {
    if( !$j.browser.msie ) {
        $j('#homepage-main-item img').hide().fadeIn(700, function(){
            $j(this).css('display', 'block');

            $j('#homepage-boxes .boxes').each(function(i) {
                $j(this).delay(100 * i).animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 300);
            });
        });

    } else {
        $j('#homepage-main-item img').css('display', 'block');
        $j('#homepage-boxes .boxes').css('opacity', 1);
    }
}

}
```

**HTML**

(The HTML code below is for only 1 box. To view the entire code please click the link below)

```
<div class="boxes-content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
```

Please Note that I did not create this code, a friend created it for me and he has not responded.

Comment: Can you add a 'alert("test1");' inside the else { } before the '$j('#homepage-main-item img').css('display', 'block');' to ensure it is reaching that point in IE. We can go from there

Comment: @Chris - I added but I do not want to leave up there for long as this is my production site, also I have no way to test this in IE 9 since I am using Windows XP (I added this into my question)

Comment: Can you copy the site to your local drive? It's going to be very hard to test otherwise. For the time I suggest you remove the 'alert' function.

Comment: Setup a virtual machine using VirtualPC, there are a couple of images available for testing Websites in different IE's http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11575

Comment: try replacing your jQuery with this one:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js

Comment: Looks like updating to the latest jQuery code worked from a screenshot tester place. Can someone verify this for me please? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that was causing the problem is `getElementsByTagName` in IE9 and the jquery version you were using was out of date 1.5 i think.  It now works in IE9 though so adding the latest version seemed to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, but it was due to `getElementsByTagName` not `getAllElementsByClassName`....screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GtA0C.gif

Comment: @sally oops I must of glanced at it and switched it in my mind.  I'll change it.